# Allow default controller mapping to be accessible via GET requests

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, error-handling

I have a Spring Boot web (using freemarker) project with the default "/error" path configured and it serves my custom error pages (403.ftl, 404.ftl, etc.).

For instance I try to access a non existing mapping such as //hostname/banana I get a 404 response with my error page displayed, as expected.

However, I would like to be able to view those pages directly in a normal GET request such as; //hostname/error/404 and view the page normally with a 200 status code. Is that possible without having to duplicate all the behavior via a new controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using **jsp** instead of **freemarker** and I used the default error page location to define my own templates and let the `DefaultErrorViewResolver` render them.

**application.properties** configuration:

```
...
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
...
```

And then I defined my custom .jsp error pages in the default location at `WEB-INF/views/error/` (in there I have; *403.jsp, 404.jsp, 4xx.jsp, 500.jsp, 502.jsp, 504.jsp, 5xx.jsp*).

And then I have a basic controller :

```
@Controller
public class ShowErrorPageController {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private DefaultErrorViewResolver errorViewResolver;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{httpStatus}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderErrorCode(@PathVariable Integer httpStatus, HttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws ServletException{

            ... (error handling, etc. etc.)

            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.valueOf(httpStatus);
            Map<String, Object> model = Collections.unmodifiableMap(addErrorAttributes(request));

            modelAndView = errorViewResolver.resolveErrorView(request, status, model);

            ...

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Then you can simply access the app and request any error pages (example: http://hostname/403) and it will respond with a HTTP 200. This was needed for me since I needed to render those pages via a proxy and didn't want to generate any HTTP error codes.